System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll 6.1 has two different assembly versions
I have been upgrading all our projects to target .NET framework 4.6.2 and I'm running into a maddening problem.  When I run the application it runs fine.  However, when I run the unit tests I get an assembly load failure:
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Source/FeatureBranch/Kernel/CDSCore.Tests/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Source\FeatureBranch\Kernel\CDSCore.Tests\bin\Debug\CDSCore.Tests.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Source/FeatureBranch/Kernel/CDSCore.Tests/bin/Debug/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Source\FeatureBranch\Kernel\CDSCore.Tests\bin\Debug\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131040.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

So if I compare the two dlls (One in the CDSCore.Tests folder and another in a system dll dir CDSCore)  See this:

They are the exact same file.  However, if I open them in ildasm you see this which shows different assembly versions.  How on earth is this the case?


It seems that the package referenced by your project was not copied correctly to the output directory of the test project, or the test project was not configured correctly. Try to compare the content of CDSCore.Tests.dll.config and CDSCore.dll.config.
